# How to convert in Date format the columns of a particular excel file?

Tags: r, dataframe, import-from-excel

I have an excel file with 77 columns (with 43 NA columns) of different length, 12 of which are Date. Ideally, I want to import it in R the dataset with the columns that refer to Date in date format, while the other columns in numeric format. There is lot of material in stackoverflow and I tried all the options but it is not working.

The first option would be to do it directly from excel:

```
dataset <- read_xlsx("Data.xlsx", col_types = "numeric") #it gives everything numeric but column date always in this format "36164"

#I also tried something like this:

dataset <- read_xlsx("Data.xlsx", col_types = c("date", rep("numeric", n))) #where "n" stands for all the columns with numbers I have but it did not work
```

I can import the data with the incorret date columns. After some cleaning (removing NA columns) I get a tbl with different column length. I tried the following codes to transform the incorrect column dates into date format:

```
dataset <- janitor::remove_empty(dataset, which = "cols") #remove NA columns
dataset <- dataset[-c(1),] #remove the first row of all columns

# Now using this command I could transform each incorrect date column into a date format:

  date <- as.Date(as.numeric(dataset$column1), origin = "1899-12-30")

# I would like to do it for all the date columns in one shot but when I try to do it in this way

  as.Date(as.numeric(dataset[,c(1,3,5,7,14,16,18,20,21,23,25,32)]), origin = "1899-12-30")

# I get an error, probably because the columns have different length
# the error is: Error in as.Date(as.numeric(var_dataset[, c(1, 3, 5, 7, 14, 16, 18, 20,  : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
# unlisting the object doesn't solve the problem
```

I am aware it is missing data to reproduce my problem but in the first scenario I don't know how to approximate my quite big excel file while in the second case I don't know how to create a tbl with many columns of different length without wasting lot of time. Sorry.

Do you have any solution? Either for importing directly from Excel or playing with the dataframe

Thanks so much

I attach here the structure of my dataset:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   5500 obs. of  77 variables:
 $ Name...1                                                     : chr  "Code" "36164" "36165" "36166" ...
 $ VSTOXX VOLATILITY INDEX - PRICE INDEX                        : chr  "VSTOXXI(PI)" "18.2" "29.69" "25.17" ...
 $ ...3                                                         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...4                                                         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...5                                                         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...6                                                         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...7                                                     : chr  "Code" "36799" "36830" "36860" ...
 $ EM COMPOSITE INDICATOR OF SOVEREIGN STRESS: GDP WEIGHTS NADJ : chr  "EMEBSCGWR" "7.8255999999999992E-2" "8.9886999999999995E-2" "8.0714999999999995E-2" ...
 $ ...9                                                         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...10                                                    : chr  "Code" "36168" "36175" "36182" ...
 $ CISS BOND MKT: GOV & NFC VOLATILITY - ECONOMIC SERIES        : chr  "EMCIBMG" "4.4651999999999997E-2" "6.6535999999999998E-2" "4.9789E-2" ...
 $ ...12                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...13                                                    : chr  "Code" "36168" "36175" "36182" ...
 $ CISS MONEY MKT: 3M RATE+ VOLATILITY - ECONOMIC SERIES        : chr  "EMECM3E" "5.7435999999999994E-2" "7.463199999999999E-2" "7.2263999999999995E-2" ...
 $ CISS FX MKT: EUR VOLATILITY - ECONOMIC SERIES                : chr  "EMECFEM" "7.2139999999999996E-2" "8.6049E-2" "4.5948999999999997E-2" ...
 $ CISS FIN INTERM: BANK+ VOLATILITY - ECONOMIC SERIES          : chr  "EMCIFIN" "4.5384999999999995E-2" "0.11820399999999999" "0.11516499999999999" ...
 $ CISS NF EQUITY: VOLATILITY - ECONOMIC SERIES                 : chr  "EMCIEMN" "7.7453999999999995E-2" "0.12733" "0.11918899999999999" ...
 $ CISS: CROSS SUBINDEXCORRELATION - ECONOMIC SERIES            : chr  "EMCICRO" "-0.21210999999999999" "-0.29791000000000001" "-0.2369" ...
 $ SYSTEMIC STRESS COMPINDICATOR - ECONOMIC SERIES              : chr  "EMCISSI" "8.4954000000000002E-2" "0.174844" "0.16546" ...
 $ ...20                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...21                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...22                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...23                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...24                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...25                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...26                                                    : chr  "Code" "33253" "33284" "33312" ...
 $ Z8 IPI: MFG., VOLUME INDEX OF PRODUCTION, 2015=100 (WDA) VOLA: chr  "Z8ES493KG" "81" "79.7" "79.400000000000006" ...
 $ ...28                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...29                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...30                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...31                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...32                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...33                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...34                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...35                                                    : chr  "Code" "35779" "35810" "35841" ...
 $ EH HICP: ALL-ITEMS NADJ                                      : chr  "EHES795WR" "1.7" "1.6" "1.6" ...
 $ ...37                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...38                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...39                                                    : chr  "Code" "35110" "35139" "35170" ...
 $ EH HICP: ALL-ITEMS (%MOM) NADJ                               : chr  "EHESPQ93R" "0.4" "0.4" "0.3" ...
 $ ...41                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...42                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...43                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...44                                                    : chr  "Code" "35445" "35476" "35504" ...
 $ EH HICP: ALL-ITEMS HICP (%YOY) NADJ                          : chr  "EHESAKZER" "2.2000000000000002" "2" "1.7" ...
 $ ...46                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...47                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...48                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...49                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...50                                                    : chr  "Code" "36206" "36234" "36265" ...
 $ EM EUROSYSTEM: BASE MONEY CURN                               : chr  "EMEBSMYBA" "426.64374199999997" "430.51499999999999" "432.34064499999999" ...
 $ ...52                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...53                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...54                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...55                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...56                                                    : chr  "Code" "35703" "35734" "35762" ...
 $ EM EUROSYSTEM: TOTAL ASSETS/LIABILITIES (EP) CURN            : chr  "EMECBSALA" "710257.53500000003" "711193.47100000002" "714957.58900000004" ...
 $ ...58                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...59                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...60                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...61                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...62                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...63                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...64                                                    : chr  "Code" "41548" "41579" "41609" ...
 $ TR EU FWD INFL-LKD SWAP 10YF20Y - MIDDLE RATE                : chr  "TREFSTT" NA NA NA ...
 $ TR EU FWD INFL-LKD SWAP 10YF10Y - MIDDLE RATE                : chr  "TREFS1T" NA NA NA ...
 $ TR EU FWD INFL-LKD SWAP 2YF2Y - MIDDLE RATE                  : chr  "TREFS22" "1.5158" "1.4669000000000001" "1.4715" ...
 $ TR EU FWD INFL-LKD SWAP 1YF1Y - MIDDLE RATE                  : chr  "TREFS11" "1.4509000000000001" "1.2338" "1.1225000000000001" ...
 $ TR EU FWD INFL-LKD SWAP 2YF3Y - MIDDLE RATE                  : chr  "TREFS23" "1.5906000000000002" "1.5453000000000001" "1.5283000000000002" ...
 $ TR EU FWD INFL-LKD SWAP 5YF10Y - MIDDLE RATE                 : chr  "TREFS5T" "2.3516000000000004" "2.3323" "2.3070000000000004" ...
 $ ...71                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...72                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...73                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...74                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ...75                                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Name...76                                                    : chr  "Code" "41255" "41286" "41317" ...
 $ TR EU FWD INFL-LKD SWAP 5YF5Y - MIDDLE RATE                  : chr  "TREFS55" "2.2027000000000001" "2.2637" "2.383" ...
```

Comment: And there's "usually" no need to specify column types. The function I mentioned does a pretty good job of guessing, based on the actual data. If you really must specify them during the reading process, you'll have to put them in the correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the col_types correctly in the `read_excel` (or read_xlsx) command. For example:

```
dataset <- read_xlsx("Data.xlsx",
     col_types=c("numeric","date","numeric","date","numeric", "date", ...))
```

**Edit**: Finally after much interrogation, the problem is that your data starts in row 3, not 2. So skip the first row (`skip=1`) and try again.

```
dataset <- read_xlsx("Data.xlsx", skip=1)
```

Comment: exactly, is there a way to do it more efficiently? I have 77 columns, some of which are just NAs. I was trying to do it like this: `read_xlsx("EONIAmonth.xlsx", col_types = c(rep("date", 1,7,10,13,26,35,39,44,50,56,64,76), rep("numeric", 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22)))`, does it make sense? It's not working so far

Comment: You've only got 34 columns as 43 are NA. If you know the classes for every column you could probably write a cute command for the col_classes argument. It would take just as long to do this as to do it manually. Edit: not make sense. But I know what you want to do. I can't believe the function can't guess correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**edit: While this will most likely solve the error you're getting, I agree with Edward's advice to use `readxl::read_excel` which should preserve the dates.**

The problem with

```
  as.Date(as.numeric(dataset[,c(1,3,5,7,14,16,18,20,21,23,25,32)]), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

is that you apply `as.numeric` on a tibble which internally is a list. Instead do

```
dplyr::mutate_at(
    dataset, 
    c(1,3,5,7,14,16,18,20,21,23,25,32), 
    dplyr::funs(as.numeric, as.Date), 
    origin = "1899-12-30",
    format = "%Y-%m-%d"
)
```

You say the columns have a different length but that's not possible in R's table-like structures (tibble, data.frame, data.table).
Lesson: Always be aware what datatype you're working with doing e.g. `str(dataset)`. `as.numeric` does not work on tables but needs to be applied to specific columns, using e.g. `mutate`.

Comment: I don't manage to make it work with `read_excel`. I don't know why. I tried your code as well but same result, it doesn't transform the code. You are right though for different columns lenght I meant that some of them have NA in place of actual numbers

Comment: When trying to apply your code I get this: `Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: NA is still counted in the length. length(c(1,2,NA))=3

Comment: @Rollo99 I edited the answer. You need to provide the `format` argument if you see that error, e.g. `format = "%Y-%m-%d"`. See `?strftime` to see how to specify the format.